# How differentiate what properties to include based on containing type info during serialization?

Tags: serialization, json.net

I have an issue related to, let's call it *differential serialization* using JSON.NET. In short, the challenge is that a different set of properties should be serialized for a type depending on the property declaration in a containing type.

```
public class ChildAttribute : Attribute {}
public class ReferenceAttribute : Attribute { }
public class ExcludeFromReferenceAttribute : Attribute { }


[DataContract]
public class Lorum
{
    [DataMember]
    [Child]
    public Ipsum SomeProp { get; private set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Reference]
    public Dolor SomeOtherProp { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Ipsum
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ExcludeFromReference]
    public int Age { get; set; }

}


[DataContract]
public class Dolor
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [ExcludeFromReference]
    public int Width { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [ExcludeFromReference]
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

When run through the json serializer, I want to apply a ruleset yielding the following result, based on the code above:

- All properties of `Lorum` should be included.
- The `Ipsum` instance referred to by the `SomeProp` property should have all its properties serialized, because it's decorated with the `Child` attribute.
- The `Dolor` instance referred to by the `SomeOtherProp` property should only have its `Name` property serialized. It *should not* have `Height` and `Weight` serialized, since `SomeOtherProp` is decorated with the `Reference` attribute, and `Height` and `Weight` are decorated with the `ExcludeFromReference` attribute.

I have looked into making a custom `ContractResolver`, but can't seem to get enough context information out of it when determining what properties to include or not: the type alone is not enough since I also need information about the property through which I access the type.

I am no JSON.NET wizard, so I may very well have missed something obvious...

Comment: A clarification-- does the `[Child]` attribute actually come into play in determining whether `[ExcludeFromReference]` should be honored, or is it controlled entirely by the presence or absence of the `[Reference]` attribute in the containing class?  I think you mean the latter, based on your comments below, but the text in your question seems to indicate the former.

Comment: Your assumption is correct: the relation will be decorated with either `[Child]` or `[Reference]`. `[ExcludeFromReference]` will be of interest only if the "containing property" is decorated with `[Reference]`. And thanks for the edit :-)